# Send String array to Kafka topic

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a Java application which streams Twitter data and sends them to Kafka topics. They are finally processed by Spark streaming.

Currently, I've been sending just `String` objects. What if I wanted to send `String []` arrays? How do I set the serialization/deserialization?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You can serialize the array using a variation of serializations, JSON, XML, Avro.. and read it on the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a custom serializer/deserializer where the first element should be the number of elements into the array (encoded as an integer) followed by every string in the array encoded as string length (an integer) followed by bytes which make the string.

Comment: Ok, I could try that. But isn't already existing any String arrays encoder/decoder?

Comment: Currently Kafka supports primitive type serializers (Integer, Boolean, String and so on). As array only Byte[ ] for binary content.

Comment: Of course my proposal is at a lower level than using a JSON serialization which is simpler but uses more bytes.

Comment: Ok, it's the closest solution to my problem. Last thing: I have this producer which I set to send Strings. If I changed the serialization to the custom one you hinted, what about the other Strings I used to sent to the other topics?

Comment: Of course when you deal with serialization/deserialization without using a schema registry (i.e. with Avro support) you have a problem that not updated consumers can't understand messages. They need to use the new deserializer for getting messages in the right way. If you have the topic already filled with simple String it could be a problem.

Comment: I don't have that kind of problem. So I could set the producer to send arrays and the consumer to read them. If a consumer needs just one string instead of an array, it just takes the element it needs. Thank you so much for your time.